# How Do I insert all records into a table using VB in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to append an Excel file, whose path I take from a control named `txtFileName` on the current form; I am trying to append it to the table `Load Report 1`.

The SQL statement causes a syntax error:

> Incomplete clause

My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Import_Click()

    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject, fileName As String, tableName As String, item As Variant, diag As Office.FileDialog

    Set diag = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    For Each item In diag.SelectedItems
        Me.txtFileName = item
    Next

    If FSO.FileExists(Me.txtFileName) Then
        DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO [Load Report1].*,Select Me.txtFileName.*,From Me.txtFileName.*")
    Else
        MsgBox "File Not Found!"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need all the commas in your SQL statement.Also, you can't access a textbox using `Me` from within an  SQL statement; you probably need to concatenate the filename together with the rest of the SQL into a single string: `"INSERT INTO [Load Report1].* SELECT [" & Me.txtFileName & "].* FROM [" & Me.txtFileName & "]"`

Comment: @ZevSpitz, Looks like a good answer to me. why don't you write it up?

Comment: @ZevSpitz I tried your code, while the VB recognize the Me.txtFileName, which is the file I select , it still gives me the incomplete clause feedback.

Comment: Please update the question with the new code you are using; in general you should do this as you try different ways to resolve the problem.